# java servlets display image in html code

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet which returns as response an html page that also includes pictures. I have those pictures stored on the file system in the Pictures folder (path: /home/andrei/Pictures). 
I currently have there just one photo(name: eu.jpg ) but i will add more.

So the point is that in the html code i somewhere have this: `<img src="/home/andrei/Pictures/eu.jpg" alt="pic" >` . But when i get the html page it doesn`t display neither the photo nor the "pic" text from alt(not sure if this is normal...). I read that it may be due to the path i gave in src but i don`t know exactly what to give.

So what path should i give to the src?

And is it normal not displaying the alt text
 because i knew that when it cannot load the pic it shows that text.

Additional information:
IDE : Eclipse Juno 
SO : Linux 
Server: Tomcat 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send back the HTML response, the client's browser will render the document and then, send requests for additional resources in order to show the HTML document fully. That includes the images, so Tomcat must be able to serve them. If you can't put them in a folder inside WebContent from the beginning, the servlet must do the move and create the document specifying the "public route".

Comment: You'll find yourself dealing with file handlers pointing to the local route to the file, then using a buffer to set the content of a new file in a relative path of the webapp. Troublesome. Why not adding the static resources to the web application?

Comment: well cause the photos add dynamically so i can t just republish, the whole app also serves as an upload. would it be sth like this?
'File originalPhoto = new File("../Pictures/..");
 File newPhoto = new Photo("/photoname.type");
'
and then copy the cotents using streams ?

Comment: An example: a webapp I worked in served some PDF files dynamically generated outside the app itself. They had to be: 1.) moved to a public location or 2.) streambuffered to be downloaded. Here, because they are images and are not meant to be downloaded but shown, the only way is to move the images to a folder available to the container.

Comment: and how can i make a folder available to the container?

Comment: It will serve stuff in the folders relative to the context. Yes, inside the webapp/MyWebapp folder... there's another option: use an Apache HTTP server in front and let him serve static resources, so you'll have a "domain" that belongs to static resources (ok, generated dynamically) like /MyAppImages that the HTTPD server will serve by itself

Comment: ok thank you very much, you saved the faith of the project :D

Answer (score 1):

Any image you intend to display in a browser connecting a web container (Tomcat in your case) must be visible in the container.  To do it, place the images in the webapp/ folder and link them properly from the servlet generating the correct  tag where path is the correct http link to your file.

Answer (score 0):

The images should be part of the webapp. Absolute FS path will not work. `<img>` will take relative path, or absolute path wrt the website.